# Program for getting and uploading latest version of a project?

Tags: unity-game-engine, version-control

I am working with a team of friends on a couple Unity3D projects.

I was wondering if there is some kind of program we can use to upload a version of our project (example: "Game1 v1.0") and then either one of us can download that version, edit it, rename the version (example "Game1 v2.0") and then reupload the updated version with the program just adding or changing the edited files and not the whole project to save time.

I hope I was clear enough on my description. 
Is there some kind of a program that can help me with this problem?

Comment: Well, that question specifically asks how to use Git for Unity, my questions asks for any program to help me with my version control and time management.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always use Git or Mercurial when working on something (even if alone).

If you want a GUI frontend, use SourceTree and BitBucket for repos (GitHub offers only public repos for free).

Comment: Can I use SourceTree and BitBucket for free?

Comment: Yes, I suggested those because they're both free.